# Blog Site navigation missing! Drupal 7.x

Tags: nodes

Hi Drupal specialists,

since today I cannot see the "page 1 of x" on the bottom of my blog page. Also the "more" button from the "latest blog posts" block is w/o functionality. I did not change anything and yesterday it was working perfect. The main menu "blog" only shows my lastest 10 posts and this is correct (I list 10 posts per page) but in total I have more than 40 posts so it should list page 1 of 4... :-(

checked for updates but all modules and the core are up-to-date.

Any idea?!

Thanks
Christian

Comment: Can you try to clear the cache in Performance section?

Comment: done 2 times but no changes, tried with 3 different browsers, everywhere the same result: no pages

Comment: resolved that by creating a new view with blog content and disabled the old 'blog' menu.

Comment: you can add that as answer, as the question remains in the *not-answered* category.